# How can I direct the output of a QProcess to a file?

Tags: qt, qprocess

I want to have the output of `qconf` redirected to `test_settings.txt` in my tmp folder.  I've thought of two possibilities:

```
QProcess procWriteProject;

procWriteProject.start("qconf", QStringList() << " -sprj "
    << projectList[0] << " >> " << "\"/tmp/testing.txt\"");

procWriteProject.start("qconf -sprj " + projectList[0] + " >> "
    + "/tmp/test_settings");
```

Will either of those work?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
QProcess procWriteProject;
procWriteProject.setStandardOutputFile("/tmp/test_settings.txt");
procWriteProject.start("qconf", QStringList() << "-sprj" << projectList[0]);
```